# What's the git url of no.de smartmachines?

Tags: git, node.js

What is the git url (the one that usually ends with .git) of the no.de smartmachines that joyent offers ?

Comment: Is it really a programming related question?

Comment: I think it is related to development and deploying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the format `yourname.no.de:repo`

[Source](http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/Getting+Started+with+a+Node.js+SmartMachine)

Comment: When I try to clone it in cloud9ide it says it's an invalid url...

Comment: Did you check the link to my source, you might find more information there.

Comment: You need SSH permissions configured to push to `no.de` from your local box. Do you have those configured in cloud9?

Comment: Yes I did Gates VP, what happened is that I needed to push definning the username "node", just like this: "git push node@myname.no.de:repo master" and that worked.